# How to integrate jQuery Lazy Load into Meta Slider WordPress plugin?

Tags: jquery-lazyload

Unfortunately for me, Meta Slider WP plugin does not support lazy load, but it's perfect for what I need -- well almost. Here's why:

I have a ton of images (per slider) that will be displayed in multiple sliders using this WP Meta Slider plugin. All sliders will use the Flex Slider option, not the other options they have available. And, as you can imagine, the page load time is awful.

I looked up lazy load and came across this site:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

It seems to be the perfect solution for what I need, but where do I need to input the snippet of coding in Meta Slider files to get this plugin to stop loading all the images at one time? What's happening is when a visitor comes to the site, this plugin loads every single image you have uploaded to it at that first-time page load which is causing the page to load awfully slow.

Additional info:

The images are pngs, 120x220 and under 50kb. I have found that converting them into jpgs instead of gifs compresses the file size to be between 12kb and 15kb, but anything lower, the images begin to lose color quality and the image color quality is extremely important.

END OF ADDITIONAL INFO

Anyway, my image database is growing and I need the images to only load upon the visitor scrolling up or down to reduce the page load time as much as possible so visitors will not be turned off and leave the site.

Thanks!

Oh, here's the plugin, I'm using:

wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/